# Getting empty object while fetching data between two Dates in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch MongoDB data using CURL with PHP. My code is like below.

```
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->apiPath . $action,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
                                        "dataSource": "' . $this->dataSource . '",
                                        "database": "' . $this->database . '",
                                        "collection": "' . $this->collection . '",
                                        "filter": { 
                                            "type": { "$eq": "'.$query.'" }                                            
                                        }
                                    }',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *',
                    'api-key: ' . $this->apiKey,
                ),
            ));
            $mongodata = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
```

I am getting output like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [documents] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 6253c5fc22d6ee83815a111a
            [lang] => Bangla
            [type] => top
            [createdAt] => 2022-04-11T00:08:54Z
            [searchTerm] => key
            [customerId] => 747498
            [wpId] => 20
            [results] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [parts] => 0
                    [pages] => 0
                    [productCategory] => 0
                )

        )
    )
)
```

But if I use below code

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->apiPath . $action,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
                                        "dataSource": "' . $this->dataSource . '",
                                        "database": "' . $this->database . '",
                                        "collection": "' . $this->collection . '",
                                        "filter": { 
                                            "type": { "$eq": "'.$query.'" },
                                            "createdOn": {
                                                "$gte": "2022-04-11T00:08:54Z",
                                                "$lt": "2022-04-11T00:08:54Z"
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    }',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *',
                    'api-key: ' . $this->apiKey,
                ),
            ));
            $mongodata = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
```

I am getting empty object like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [documents] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: What is "$gte": "2022-04-11T00:08:54Z" and "$lt": "2022-04-11T00:08:54Z"? This is the same timestamp...you need a range...

Comment: Thanks @nimrodserok. Actually I would like to fetch data of a Date using Date range. Thanks.

Comment: So when you use a range is it working for you?

Comment: Thanks @nimrodserok. No, it is not working for me. Actually I don't know how to pass Date. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, just suggesting to use old date at `$gte` and newer date at `$lt`

Comment: Thanks @nimrodserok. Actually I am going to use old date at `$gte` and newer date at `$lt`. But currently I am testing my code using only one Date. I know there is a value in this specific Date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no logical set of documents that can fit this condition as its `createdOn` should be **both** greater than or equal to X and less than X.
This query will always return an empty set:

```
db.collection.find({
  createdOn: {
    $gte: ISODate("2022-04-11T00:08:54Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2022-04-11T00:08:54Z")
  }
})
```

Even for this document:

```
  {
    createdOn: ISODate("2022-04-11T00:08:54Z"),
    a: 2
  }
```

Check it on [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2xCHjnpY1yw)

Comment: Thanks @nimrod serok. I have a value on Date `[createdAt] => 2022-04-11T00:08:54Z` (You can see my post). Now I am using this code. https://pastebin.mozilla.org/vKCQYBag. I am getting `Invalid syntax error: TypeError: invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value` error. Thanks.